Output of Postman in Azure Devops is width limited
I'm running a Postman script with the Newman CLI within an Azure Devops pipeline. I'm trying to get a variable out of Postman and back to the pipeline in order to use it elsewhere, so in the Postman collection I have;
console.log('##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVariable]stringtobesaved');

The process works up to a point. For some reason Newman is splitting the command and giving me a short variable;
MyVariable = stringtobe

And then I can see a separate line in the log showing;
saved

If I change the variable name or the variable value, it would seem that it's always cut at the 53rd character. If it so happens that my variable name is a bit long, for example;
console.log('##vso[task.setvariable variable=MylongerVariable]stringtobesaved');

I get an error message saying '##vso[task.setvariable variable=MylongerVar' isn't a valid command. I am fairly sure it's Newman at fault here, if I do;
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IHaveAVeryLongVariable]AndAnEvenLongerValue"

Then it works fine.
Can anyone tell me why it truncates at 53 characters, and whether I can increase the limit? As a guide, I ultimately want to put around 400 characters into a variable, so 53 is a significant limit.

We may have a solution, turns out the test name isn't limited or wrapped. By adding the ##vso command as a test, that will allow it to be picked up by Azure. As an example, in the test post-request;
pm.variables.set("testname","##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyReallyLongVariable]AndReallyLongValue"));
pm.test(pm.variables.get("testname"), () => {
    pm.expect(true).to.eq(true);
});


